# Given a Map how to sort by value and if value matches sort by key Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Given Map

```
{
  'i' => 2, 
  'love' => 2, 
  'leetcode' => 1, 
  'coding' => 1
}
```

I want to,

- Sort the `Map` based on value
- if the value matches, sort by key where the word with the lower alphabetical order comes first.

Expected

```
{
  "i" => 2, 
  "love" => 2, 
  "coding" => 1,
  'leetcode' => 1, 
}
```

**Solution i have tried**

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("i", 2);
map.set("love", 2);
map.set("coding", 1);
map.set("live", 1);

let output = new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => {
  //if b[0] and a[0] matches sort by  key stuck here
  return b[0] - a[0];
  
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Subtraction works with numbers. For strings, `compareFunction` should be `b[0].localeCompare(a[0])`

Comment: btw, `...map.entries()` is the same as just spreading the map `...map`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Value is present at index `1` so update the index to `1` for sorting based on value and use [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for string comparison.

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("i", 2);
map.set("love", 2);
map.set("coding", 1);
map.set("live", 1);

// for sorting based on number we need to return the difference
// in case those are equals difference would be 0(falsy value)
// and the or part will be executed and returns(string comaprison)
let output = new Map([...map].sort((a,b) => b[1] - a[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0]) ));

console.log(...output);
```

---

or with ES6 [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("i", 2);
map.set("love", 2);
map.set("coding", 1);
map.set("live", 1);

let output = new Map([...map].sort( ([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1 || k1.localeCompare(k2) ));

console.log(...output);
```

***FYI :*** To get a basic idea of how [Logical operators refer to MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description).

Comment: Can you also please explain it will be great rather than just the answer

Comment: @RahulSingh :  added some basic explanation

Comment: yes those two lines made me accept the ans over @Nina

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort the count descending and the string with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) ascending.

The first part takes a delta of the two values and while [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is expecting a value

- smaller than zero for then `a` is smaller then `b`, which means both have the right order, like `1 - 2` where you get `-1`,
- equal zero, that means bot elements have the same value, like `7 - 7`, or
- greater than zero, which means both elements have to swap, like `5 - 3`.

The same result returns `localeCompare` with strings.

```js
let map = new Map();
map.set("coding", 1);
map.set("love", 2);
map.set("live", 1);
map.set("i", 2);

let output = new Map([...map].sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0])));

console.log([...output]);
```

Comment: *Sort the Map based on value and if value matches sort by key* So, `b[1] -a[1] || a[0].localeCompare(b[0])`

Comment: @Nina i guess you missed it , this only compares the string keys not the values and if values matches then you compare keys

Comment: Can you also please explain it will be great rather than just the answer